# file_get_contents(https://devel.loc/content): failed to open stream: Connection refused

Tags: docker

I use docker with nginx and php-fpm containers.

When I open https://devel.loc/content in the browser everything is ok (this is dynamicly served data).

When I try to open this url via file_get_contents from https://devel.loc/loadContent I get: failed to open stream

php.ini has:
allow_url_fopen = On

Strange is that when I use external address for example 'https://facebook.com' to fetch data everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with nginx container configuration.

There is a need to added to alias.

```
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    build: ./nginx/
    networks:
      network:
        aliases:
          - devel.loc
```